# String replacement in iOS for HTML tags

Tags: ios, regex, uiwebview, nsstring

I am parsing a string for `UIWebview` in `iOS`.

I have a data as -

```
<p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.someurl.com/bikes/triumph-motorcycles-plans-sell-2700-units-2015-16/">Triumph Motorcycles Plans To Sell Over 2700 Units By 2015-16</a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.someurl.com">MotorBuzz -  Car Bike News &amp; Reviews</a>.</p>
```

What I want is to **remove hyper link of a text. I dont want to remove text I just want to disable the hyper link of the text**.

So for above data it should looks like -

```
 <p>The post Triumph Motorcycles Plans To Sell Over 2700 Units By 2015-16 appeared first on MotorBuzz -  Car Bike News &amp; Reviews.</p>
```

So plz let me know any regex or any string replacment solution in **iOS/Objective -C**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily since you have such a simple requirement I can skip the whole [don't use regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) thing and move straight onto the solution.

Match this:

```
<a( [^>]*?)?>|</a>
```

and replace it with nothing, that will remove all anchor tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `NSAttributedString`. First you convert your html string into an `NSAttributedString`, and then get the actual string from that.

```
NSString *html = @"<p>The post <a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://www.someurl.com/bikes/triumph-motorcycles-plans-sell-2700-units-2015-16/\">Triumph Motorcycles Plans To Sell Over 2700 Units By 2015-16</a> appeared first on <a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://www.someurl.com\">MotorBuzz -  Car Bike News &amp; Reviews</a>.</p>";

   NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                      options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                                NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                                           documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    NSString *actualString= [attrString string];
```

But it will remove all the html tags from the string.